# Why does ifconfig on my raspberry show a different IPv6 address than the router shows for the raspberry?

Tags: networking, router, raspberry-pi, ipv6, fritzbox

Reaching a Rasperry Pi in a home network over the internet using IPv6 fails. While searching for the cause of the problem I noticed that `ifconfig` on the Pi shows a different IPv6 than the router (FritzBox). **How is this possible?**

**Setup**

- **HomeA** uses a internet connection with a public IPv6 address. A FritzBox 7590 is uses as router.
- Within the home network of HomeA a Synology Diskstation and a Raspberry Pi are running.
- The FritzBox is configured to allow access to the Diskstation and to the Pi from the internet. Disksation and Pi have the exact same privileges/settings.
- `ifconfig` on this **Diskstation** shows the **exact same** IPv6 address as the FritzBox shows for this device.
- `ifconfig` on this **PI** shows **different** IPv6 address than the FritzBox shows for Pi.
- `ping6` to the IPv6 of the Diskstation is no problem. Both from the the local network and from remote devices over the internet. Accessing other services (HTTP, OpenVPN, etc.) on this Diskstations is also no problem.
- All attempts to access the Raspberry Pi using IPv6 fail.

Config

```
// ifconfig on the Pi (with obfuscate addresses)
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.201.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.201.255
    inet6 2a00:aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee:ffff:79e4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 fe80::aabb:ccdd:eee:fff  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:aa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 424105  bytes 107106102 (102.1 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 145621  bytes 80021709 (76.3 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

While this shows `2a00:aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee:ffff:79e4` (obfuscate) as IPv6 address, the FritzBox show a **completly different IPv6 address** for the Pi (same prefix but different ending): `2a00:aaaa:bbbb:cccc:1111:2222:3333:c2a9`

Running a `ping6` on the IPv6 shown in the FritzBox fails, while pinging the IPv6 shown in the Pi works:

```
// Ping to Pi from computer in HomeA network
$ ping6 2a00:aaaa:bbbb:cccc:1111:2222:3333:c2a9  // FritzBox IP       - FAILS
$ ping6 2a00:aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee:ffff:79e4  // ifconfig IP on Pi - OK

// Ping to Pi from a remote computer 
$ ping6 2a00:aaaa:bbbb:cccc:1111:2222:3333:c2a9  // FritzBox IP       - FAILS
$ ping6 2a00:aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee:ffff:79e4  // ifconfig IP on Pi - FAILS

// Ping to Diskstation from local OR remote computer
$ ping6 2a00:disk:stat:ioni:pv6...               // same on Pi and on FritzBox - OK

// Using IPv6 on the Pi itself
$ ping6 google.com                               // OK
```

While reaching the Diskstation is no problem (both local and remote) a `ping6` is only possible in the local network using the IPv6 address `ifconfig` shows on the Pi.

I double checked the config in the FritzBox. The Pi has exactly the same privileges/settings as the Disksation. There seems to be something wrong with the config of the Pi itself.

**What might be wrong with the Pi? How is it possible, that the IPv6 address in `ifconfig` and in the Router are different?**

Comment: Are there any "Wi-Fi extenders" or other similar devices between the Fritzbox and the Pi? Does either of those addresses for the Pi contain `..ff:fe..` in the middle of the second half?

Comment: Is it possible you have a double-NAT situation?

Comment: @user1686 The Pi has a wired connection directly to the router. No `..ff:fe..` in the addresses.

@harrymc Not double-NAT that I would be aware of. The router has a fiber cable connection to the internet with a public IPv6 address and provider internal IPv4 address (CGNAT). Diskstation and Pi are connected in exactly the same way, so both devices should face the same problems, shouldn't they? But the Diskstation can be accessed without any problem while the Pi cannot be reached at all.